# can't use WMI Classes in C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I hope you can help me out another time :)

I like to use the WMI Classes, such as ConnectionOptions, ManagementScope and so on, to reboot a remote Desktop. Anyway, I tried to include the System.Management thing but it still can´t find the classes and cause me to not to debug it...

using System.Management;

Does I need to install something first? oO
I use Visual Studio 2012 on a windows 7 PC, the tool is made of a C# WPF Application...

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Did you also add the reference to the System.Management.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a reference to `System.Management` assembly. You don't need to install anything else.

After you write the code, it ***might*** be required that your app runs with elevated privileges in order for the WMI functionality to actually work when calling it.